# JavaScript function not executing at all

Tags: javascript

The code isn't doing anything at all, the images are just staying still

Here's the code, I commented where the function that isn't running is

If the question is too vague ask me for details, I don't know how to explain this more simple than it already is

```
var Car=function(x,y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
};

Car.prototype.draw=function() {
    var carHtml='<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';
    this.carElement=$(carHtml);
    this.carElement.css({
        position:"absolute",
        left:this.x,
        top:this.y,
    });
    $("body").append(this.carElement);
};

Car.prototype.moveRight=function() { // Function that isn't working
    this.x+=5;
    this.carElement.css({
        left:this.x,
        top:this.y
    });
};
var tesla=new Car(20,20);
var nissan=new Car(100,200);
tesla.draw();
nissan.draw();
var ID=setInterval(nissan.moveRight(),1500);
```

Comment: `var ID=setInterval(nissan.moveRight.bind(nissan),1500);`

Comment: the first argument of setInterval is a function, so don't call it : setInterval(nissan.moveRight.bind(...),1500);

Comment: I want to also point out that `left` and `top` CSS properties must have a unit. `left: 20` is invalid. Use `left: this.x+"px"` to specify the unit.

Comment: @Dark

Didn't know about that, I'll look into it, thanks! (I'm new to using CSS, I'm used to using offset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with this line

```
var ID=setInterval(nissan.moveRight(),1500);
```

The first argument of [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) is a `function` or a callback function. So you either need to pass only `nissan.moveRight` or put it inside a function

```
var ID=setInterval(function(){nissan.moveRight()},2500);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/t4tvn9zs/3/)